# Opening URL works in Run box but not in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, url, cmd

When I open a URL through the Run box it executes successfully, but not when put in a batch script.

When I try to run this URL in a batch script

```
com.epicgames.launcher://apps/fn%3A4fe75bbc5a674f4f9b356b5c90567da5%3AFortnite?action=launch&silent=true
```

it returns this error

```
com.epicgames.launcher://apps/fn%3A4fe75bbc5a674f4f9b356b5c90567da5%3AFortnite?action=launch&silent=true
'com.epicgames.launcher:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'silent' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

but when I run it in the Run box, it works normally.

Comment: As a side issue to your specific problem, every single one of those `%` characters, in a batch file, needs to be changed to `%%`, and the entire URI should be doublequoted too!

Answer (score 0):

A batch file can only execute .exe, .com and other batch files.

Use the `start` command to launch other things:

```
@echo off
start http://example.com/?foo^&bar
```

And as noted in the comments, you need to deal with special characters. `%` must be changed to `%%` and `&` to `^&` etc...